# Calculate maximum argument passed to a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I'm trying to calculate maximum argument passed to a bash script. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

max=$1

for var in "$@"
do
    if ($var>$max)
    then
        max=$var
    fi
done

echo $max
```

Here is what I get:

```
$ /bin/sh my_script 1 2 3
rgz: 11: 1: not found
rgz: 11: 2: not found
rgz: 11: 3: not found
1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That you now have a file named "1" in your current directory should be a clue...

Comment: There really is a file named "1" in my current directory, but I don't understand why...

Comment: `$var>$max` is being interpreted as "run the command in `$var`, putting the output in the file named by `$max`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you -

```
#!/bin/bash

max="$1"
for var in "$@"
do
    if [ "$var" -gt "$max" ] # Using the test condition
    then
        max="$var"
    fi
done
echo "$max"
```

Comment: good one, just a few comments: the original used `#!/bin/sh` as shebang, yours correctly use `#!/bin/bash` it's important to know that sh is different (even when aliased to bash); I'd rather use `((` instead of `[` but even if you use that it's best to choose `[[` over `[`

Comment: Thanks @Samus_ for the comments. I may be wrong here but isn't `[[` used when you do compounded conditionals i.e when checking for two  or more conditionals?

Answer (score 0):

This is mine. Minor improvement...

```
#!/bin/bash

max="$1"
for v in "$@"
do
  [[ $v -gt $max ]] && max=$v
done
echo "$max"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @WouterJ I was just providing a shorter version to the accepted answer.

Comment: that should be in a comment.

Comment: If you can find a good way to format that in a comment I'm all for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the results to `sort` and find the maximum (the last item in the sorted list) with `tail`:

```
your stuff | sort -n | tail -1
```

May be this is not the computationally most efficient way to get the maximum, but gets the job done.